# Selecting a unique pair satisfying a condition $\varphi$ with an ordering

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic, foundations

Given a finite structure $\mathfrak{A}$ with Universe $|A| < \infty$ and signature $\tau$. We say a pair $(a,a') \in A$ satisfies a $\tau$-formular $\varphi$ iff

$$ \mathfrak{A} \models \varphi(a,a').$$

Additionally, we have an extension $\mathfrak{A}'$ of the structure $\mathfrak{A}$ which adds a strict ordering $<$ on $A$. Hence, we can express properties with $\tau \cup \{<\}$-formulas. But $\varphi$ does not depend on $<$.

We assume that there is at *least one* pair satisfying $\varphi$.

With the help of this ordering we want to make $\varphi$ *unique*. Hence, we are looking for a $\tau \cup \{<\}$-formula $\psi$ s.t. there is exactly one pair $(a,a') \in A$ with $\mathfrak{A}' \models \psi(a,a')$ and $(a,a')$ also satisfies $\varphi$.

> Without the formalism: We have a property $\varphi$ (not dependent on the
>   ordering) satisfied by several pairs. We want to select a unique pair
>   by using a pre-existing ordering.

A natural solution is the lexicographically minimal pair $(a,a')$ which satisfies $\varphi$:

\begin{align*}
\mathsf{lexmin}(\varphi,a,a') := & \varphi(a,a')\land \\
& \lnot \exists b,b' (a<b \land \varphi(b,b'))\land \\
& \lnot \exists b,b' (a=b \land a' < b' \land \varphi(b,b')\\
\end{align*}

I need this in a proof which requires me to use few axillary variables i.e. $b,b'$ in this context. Is it also possible to make the pair unique with just one auxiliary variable?

Comment: The solution is not natural at all. What if $<$ is a dense order and there is no least element to the set of $a$ for which there is $a'$ such that $\varphi(a,a')$ holds?

Comment: For example consider $\tau$ to be a signature with no constants, functions or relation symbols except equality. $A$ is countable and $<$ is the order of the rational numbers (you can even assume $A=\Bbb Q$ for simplicity). Now $\varphi(x,y)$ is $x\neq y$. You're looking for something that picks exactly a single pair satisfying $\varphi$, but a simple automorphism argument shows that there isn't any single pair.

Comment: Okay, you're right. I tried to make this problem as general as possible. But it back-fired. $A$ is finite. Furthermore, we assume that there is always a pair which satisfies $\varphi$.